# How to make a Record in TypeScript can accept different types

Tags: typescript, types, record

I want to ask about Record in TypeScript, currently when I use Record as parameter type in a function then I get error in my code because it can't accept different type.

```
type Keys = 'name' | 'qty';

const getValueByKey = <T = any>(items: Record<Keys, T>, key: Keys) => {
  return items[key];
}
```

```
getValueByKey({ name: 'fulan', qty: 1}, 'name'); // Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcoF4oHIB2BDAthNUAPugI6hoDcAUFQMYD2GCwUA5hMAGpYA2ArhABCIOCBRQAPABVxWDCAB8ACgCWwCDgQAuKACUIDAE4ATCaIQAaKFIVWA1vB3mAlCgVQA3lShRDHPoYYUGoaCADaDiAAutQAvjTsXLwCwqJKHlDYeDpoAGZ8PHJoVmQgOgCMsVaYuPjOFFAA9I3W4NCYfDgARhCGBCpIGPQsWAgIKqzYXTzQwPRQoJDozIYqGKxoAHRKAEwAzDs7zkA)

The goal is actually to get the type of the value in the function.

How can I make a Record accept values of different types? Thank you

Comment: Okay, I mean that my answer was off-topic, so I delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you want to do is to accept an object type that has the keys in your union, and return a value from the object based on the `key` parameter while also inferring what constitutes a valid `key` parameter from the object that is provided. This type of inference is possible using [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).

> Keep in mind that TypeScript is [structurally typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#structural-typing), so any object that has the keys `name` and `qty` will be allowed (even if it has additional keys), and you'll be able to use any key from that object for the `key` argument.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hJQLxQOQDsCGBbCKoB9UBHUFAbgCgKAzAVzQGNgBLAezSgHMJgA1DADa0IAIRBwEAHgpQoAFSgQAHsAhoAJgGcoAJQgNWAJ3WSJAGigY0IAHxmZsRSrVaoAa3itq8+zYAUzKpYmgBcPu7wYTAAlGFyANowALpQAN4Ohjy0hhyBEMHxHiBJlAC+VAZomsBQrABGAFZIaZg4YSh0AlYoFiQgYQCMpZQUldVQAG6CwgPN3HzTouLwfvUNFujYuNGUsrIA9PsAegD8FezjU0IQAExzPPzXYhKrjRt9KDsOB8dnoxc1K7CADM9wWT2WIFe61QaFYwAA+hgEUVPpQgA)

```ts
type Key = 'name' | 'qty';

function getValueByKey <
  T extends Record<Key, any>,
  K extends keyof T,
>(items: T, key: K): T[K] {
  return items[key];
}

const obj = {name: 'fulan', qty: 1};

const value1 = getValueByKey(obj, 'name');
    //^? const value1: string

const value2 = getValueByKey(obj, 'qty');
    //^? const value2: number
```

and if you try to use a key that's not in the object, TS will (appropriately) emit a compiler diagnostic error:

```ts
const value3 = getValueByKey(obj, 'not_a_key');
//                                ~~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type '"not_a_key"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"name" | "qty"'. (2345)
```

Comment: Hello @jsejcksn thanks for your answer. But what if I want to get all types of value? example, if the function is like this

```const value1 = getValueByKey({name: 'Item1', qty: 1}, 'name');```

then expect value1 is ```string | number```

is it possible? thanks

Comment: @Shbdn Then that type would be less correct. Can you explain why you would want a [wider](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) and less correct type? If the purpose of the function is to return the value in the object at the key provided in the argument, then why would you want to show other return types which don't relate to that value?

Comment: @Shbdn If you simply want a type which represents the union of all values in an object, you can use [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoapaN): `type Values<T> = T[keyof T]`.